# PHP curl ; symbol on url

Tags: php, curl

I need to access this URL on php:
https://wmf.ok.ru/play;jsessionid=a-pt2O8FJKq_wzqod9LAJNtwgjNSjaNa-KVIGc1d1eRUSWhdAw9dlDo13fLzh57rGyKPzk2V0jMFrnKw8R4HjA.p162X6pZ_FG0kKMmKa6bkQ?client=flash&jsonp=&tid=40542951634095&ctx=my

But on my PHP code I got 404 error. I have done everything correctly. I think there is a mistake with ; symbol. We can open the link above on chrome, but not on php curl. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);

    function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,az;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7,uz;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5',
            'Referer: https://ok.ru/',
            'Origin: https://ok.rus'
        ));
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        if(curl_error($ch))
        {
            echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
        echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }

    $url = 'https://wmf.ok.ru/play;jsessionid=a-pt2O8FJKq_wzqod9LAJNtwgjNSjaNa-KVIGc1d1eRUSWhdAw9dlDo13fLzh57rGyKPzk2V0jMFrnKw8R4HjA.p162X6pZ_FG0kKMmKa6bkQ?client=flash&jsonp=&tid=40542951634095&ctx=my';
    echo file_get_contents_curl($url);
?>
```

After executing this code, I got microsoft's server 404 error. How can I make Curl to open URLs like this?

Comment: Have you tried using `rawurlencode()` on your url?

Comment: I think you need to encode the url before passing it to curl opts

Comment: I have tried rawurlencode and urlencode too. None of them worked. Can someone show me example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your function and it will work:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
```

Here is the full working function:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,az;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7,uz;q=0.6,ru;q=0.5',
    'Referer: https://ok.ru/',
    'Origin: https://ok.rus'
    ));
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    if(curl_error($ch))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);

    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

$url = 'https://wmf.ok.ru/play;jsessionid=a-pt2O8FJKq_wzqod9LAJNtwgjNSjaNa-KVIGc1d1eRUSWhdAw9dlDo13fLzh57rGyKPzk2V0jMFrnKw8R4HjA.p162X6pZ_FG0kKMmKa6bkQ?client=flash&jsonp=&tid=40542951634095&ctx=my';

echo file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

?>

Comment: It worked on my computer. You can try to look at the network tab in Chrome, copy the request to this page as CURL and paste it in the Terminal/CMD, then check if it works. Later try to use a website like this to turn the CURL into a working PHP code: https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

Comment: Yes it worked on WAMP too, but it don't worked on server. :( Thanks for your answer

Comment: I think one of the PHP extensions is not installed on the server. You can try to create a <?php phpinfo(); ?> and run it on the server and check what is installed on the server.

Comment: which one is not installed?

Comment: which one is required?

Comment: I don't know, try to compare it with the results of your local machine.